# install Ubuntu/Linux on internal hard drive or on external hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, external-hdd, syslinux

I want to install Ubuntu/Linux on my laptop because I really hate windows 10!! I think windows 10 is not totally compatible with the hardware of my laptop or I do not know what happen, but I have several issues such as slow initial booting, it is slow to turn off the laptop and more issues. I have a dell inspiron with 16 GB RAM, 128GBSSD (OS installed there) and 1TB SATA, core i7 and nvidia 4GB, so pretty good stuff for using google chrome and couple other softwares.

I am really decided to change to linux as my OS, but after reading several experiences the best solution is to either dual boot windows and linux or install LInux on a external hard disk. I am not a computer expert, so I need some guidance to know the best option (preserve windows and not mess the internal hard disk) and to install linux.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't! If you think the factory installed OS is not "totally compatible" and you don't understand why such things happens (or why they are what they are) and you don't know how to troubleshoot it (in Windows), I would say you need to learn a few (OK, a LOT of) things before installing an OS.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best choice is to test a linux distribution first on your computer. First find out if Windows boots from EFI or BIOS with `bcdedit` command to execute as administrator in windows shell (if you see a .efi you are EFI).

Then create a bootable USB key accordingly allowing you to test a live distribution without installing. When you are satisfied (test hardware compatibility), just install from the key, and the installer should ask you about installing linux and keeping Windows next to it.

Answer (score -1):

Install it on the internal drive.

Internal drives are always faster than external drives of the same type, so If you install on an external drive you should experience longer loading times for the OS itself and any programs you will install on it. Also file management (copying/moving/deleting/loading files) will be slower.
You will not mess up your Windows files if you do the partitioning job right. Just make sure that there will be no sudden blackouts in your area if you are using a desktop, and if you are using a laptop then just make sure your battery is charged to 100%.